# getElementById returns element but then returns null

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

So I'm trying to set up some references of some DOM elements in my JS. However, for some reason, they return the correct elements, but then return null shortly after. So i tried wrapping them in an if check to make sure the elements aren't null to prevent this. however, it still seems to be happening.

resizer.js

```
// Define DOM elements
const resizer = document.getElementById('resizer');
let btnMob;
let btnTablet;
let btnLaptop;
let btnDesktop;

// Check buttons exist and asign to variables if they do
if (document.getElementById('resizer-mob') !== null) {
    btnMob = document.getElementById('resizer-mob');
}
if (document.getElementById('resizer-tablet') !== null) {
    btnTablet = document.getElementById('resizer-tablet');
}
if (document.getElementById('resizer-laptop') !== null) {
    btnLaptop = document.getElementById('resizer-laptop');
}
if (document.getElementById('resizer-desktop') !== null) {
    btnDesktop = document.getElementById('resizer-desktop');
}

// Define string constants
const DESKTOP_CLASS = 'resizer--desktop';
const LAPTOP_CLASS = 'resizer--laptop';
const TABLET_CLASS = 'resizer--tablet';
const MOB_CLASS = 'resizer--mob';

// Check elements have been asign correctly
console.log('mob is ', btnMob);
console.log('tablet is ', btnTablet);
console.log('laptop is ', btnLaptop);
console.log('desktop is ', btnDesktop);


// Update resizer to display desktop
btnDesktop.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("DESKTOP");
    resizer.classList.remove(LAPTOP_CLASS);
    resizer.classList.remove(TABLET_CLASS);
    resizer.classList.remove(MOB_CLASS);

    resizer.classList.add(DESKTOP_CLASS);
});

// Update resizer to display laptop
btnLaptop.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("LAPTOP");
    resizer.classList.remove(DESKTOP_CLASS);
    resizer.classList.remove(TABLET_CLASS);
    resizer.classList.remove(MOB_CLASS);

    resizer.classList.add(LAPTOP_CLASS);
});

// Update resizer to display tablet
btnTablet.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("TABLET");
    resizer.classList.remove(DESKTOP_CLASS);
    resizer.classList.remove(LAPTOP_CLASS);
    resizer.classList.remove(MOB_CLASS);

    resizer.classList.add(TABLET_CLASS);
});

// Update resizer to display mobile
btnMob.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("MOB");
    resizer.classList.remove(DESKTOP_CLASS);
    resizer.classList.remove(LAPTOP_CLASS);
    resizer.classList.remove(TABLET_CLASS);

    resizer.classList.add(MOB_CLASS);
});
```

Comment: This is quite unclear... `document.getElementById` works on every browser in the world, so if it tells the ID is not present on the page, it's because it is not present (it is what it means when it doesn't return an element). Plus, there is no question in your post: what answer do you expect?

Comment: I know. That is why this is baffling me. The elements are present. I can see them on the screen. But for some reason after about 1s they all return null :/

Comment: in terms of answer I’m hoping someone can see what I’ve done wrong here. It’s pretty basic, which is infuriating 

Comment: This is very likely because your script is run before the elements are inserted in the DOM, you do know that order matter on a HTML page? Where is your script inside your page? I bet the script is in the header, which means before the body ;) Try to insert it just before the body closing tag.

Comment: Script is located in the footer. The elements exist as it finds them initially, but then returns them again as null

Comment: A browser does not lie! Please provide a reproducible fiddle or better, a stackoverflow snippet with your HTML page + the JS. Only way to get some help if your script is actually properly loaded.

Comment: @sjahan that's not an issue here of it running, as it only runs on click.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried != instead of !==?
And it returns null or undefined?

If it's undefined you need to use:

```
typeof(element) != 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is behaving as expected.  The first time you run the code everything works as you haven't deleted any elements.  The second time you have, and so some elements return `null` because they don't exist anymore.

Comment: except i havent deleted any elements. They're still in the DOM and i can see them